# How to find Jacobian?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I've learned to find Jacobian where x is equal to something and y is equal to something. Here I have the following problem: $u = x + 2y$ and $v = x - y$, in this case, how am I supposed to get $\partial(x,y) \over \partial(u,v)$? In other words, how to find $\partial x \over \partial u$?

Comment: @imranfat So ${\partial x \over \partial u }= 1$ and ${\partial x \over \partial v} = 0$? And what about for $y$? I can rewrite both terms with $y$ on left side, do I need to take partial four times then?

Comment: My suggestion was incomplete. The provided answer that you accepted, is indeed precise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is true that you are given $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, these transformations are invertible, namely that $x$ and $y$ can also be expressed as functions of $u$ and $v$.

In  this case, note that $u = x+2y$ and $v = x-y$. Multiply the second equation by two and add it to the first, and you get $3x =2v+u$, so that $x = \frac{2v+u}3$. Now, if we subtract the second equation from the first, then we get $3y = u-v$, so $y=\frac{u-v}3$.

Hence, we are in a position to calculate the Jacobian:
$$
J = \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}  & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{3} & \dfrac{2}{3} \\ \dfrac{1}{3}  & \dfrac{-1}{3}\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Ok, so the catch here is to try to rewrite them into $x$ equal to only $u$ and $v$, and $y$ equal to only $u$ and $v$ too? Btw, the answer from your formula is the correct one! Thanks.

Comment: @user321070 You are welcome. By the way, I want to see if you find a relation between the Jacobian $\frac{\partial (u.v)}{\partial (x,y)}$ with this one.

Comment: Yeah, that was quite straight forward and I got $-3$.

Comment: My point is, the product of the two Jacobians should be $1$. Therefore, there is actually no need to invert the transformation, it is  enough to calculate this Jacobian, and then find it's inverse, as another answer has done. Since you did not know this, I thought it might be good to point out.

Comment: I see! Thanks, I learned yet another new thing!

Comment: You are welcome, @user321070

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon : how does one find the jacobian of the jacobian? i.e., iterating the jacobian?

Comment: @MSIS The Jacobian is a map from $\mathbb R^2$ to the space of $2 \times 2$ matrices, so if it's a differentiable map you can then create a "Jacobian of a Jacobian" by decomposing the Jacobian itself into it's "component maps" (so treat the map as $J : (a,b) \to (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b), \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b), \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(a,b), \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(a,b))$ for example) and then it's just like another multi-valued differentiable function. The only difference is that the "Jacobian of the Jacobian" will have more components as a matrix.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative:

$$
\begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}  & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} \\ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}  & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$

$$
=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1  & -1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$

$$
=\begin{pmatrix} \dfrac13 & \dfrac23 \\ \dfrac13  & -\dfrac13\end{pmatrix}
$$

Note This these types of problems become much harder once you no longer have linear expressions for $u$ and $v$.

Comment: That's a very interesting way of looking at it. Great answer.